# binding backbone form view UIto model change to enable and disable "save" button

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I am creating form something like this using backbone, underscore and backbone.stickit  libraries. My screen most look [somewhat like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Lasang/Mp6G9/198/embedded/result/) .

### form html

```
<form id="main">
<div>
    <label for="words">words: <input name="words" type="text"/></label>     
</div>
 <div>
    <label for="type">type: <input name="type" type="text"/></label>     
</div>

    <div>
        <input id="okButton" class="btn" value="save"/>
   </div>
```

### backbone model/view

```
 var app = {
 Model: Backbone.Model.extend({}),
 View: Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.setElement($('#main'));
    },
    bindings: {
        'input[name=words]': 'words',
        'input[name=type]': 'type',
        'input#okButton': {
          attributes: [{
            name: 'disabled',
            observe:['type','words'],
            onGet: 'okButtonDisabled'
          }],
        }
    },
    okButtonDisabled: function(words) {
        return words[0].length > 0 ? null : true;
    },
    addDisabledClass: function(words) {
        return words[0].length > 0 ? "" : "disabled";
    },
    render: function() {
        this.stickit();
    }
 })
 };
```

When user enter some value in type field, the "save" button gets enabled, otherwise it is disabled.

The above examples binds only type field. it does not act for "words" fields.

## Thing I am working on

The jsfiddle for the form I am working on is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lasang/Mp6G9/201/).

### form html

```
 <form id="main">
 <div>
     <label for="words">words: <input name="words" type="text"/></label>     
 </div>
 <div>
     <label for="type">type: <input name="type" type="text"/></label>     
 </div>
 </form>
```

### model/view code

```
var app = {
Model: Backbone.Model.extend({}),
View: Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.setElement($('#main'));
    },
    bindings: {
        'input[name=words]': 'words',
        'input[name=type]': 'type',
        'input#okButton': {
          attributes: [{
            name: 'disabled',
            observe:['type','words'],
            onGet: 'okButtonDisabled'
          }],
        }
    },
    okButtonDisabled: function(words) {
        return words[0].length > 0 ? null : true;
    },
    addDisabledClass: function(words) {
        return words[0].length > 0 ? "" : "disabled";
    },
    render: function() {
        this.stickit();
    }
  })
 };
 var model = new app.Model({
   words: "apple",
   type: "fruit"
 });
 var view = new app.View({
    model: model
 });
 view.render();
```

### What I am trying to do is:

- set initially the "save" button as  disabled.
- If user makes any changes to any of form field, it must enable "save" button.
- But, if user enters something in any field so that "save" button  is enabled, and again make the  field same as original , the "save" button must be disabled again. i.e. editing "apple" to "apppleee" so that "save" is enabled, and reverse "appleee" back to "apple" to disable "save" button again.

***Thanks for help in advance.***

Comment: I'm confused by your logic. If the "save" button is enabled on change of any field, but the "word" field is still == "apple"... wouldn't the "save" button then be disabled? Do you want the "save" button to be enabled if ANY field changes from its' default?

Comment: @Corey you are right. i want to button to be enabled it any of model changes from defaults, be the feild word or type. That is to say, allow user to save only if any feild changes. if they change, and again they like to edit and come back to orginal, then disable since the fields are same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest adding some logic (function) to your model to check an objects value against its' default. Then, in your `okButtonDisabled` method, call the model method to check for default values. Here is an example from the code you have supplied:

```
var app = {
    Model: Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            words: "apple",
            type: "fruit"
        },

        isDefault: function(key) {
            return this.get(key) === this.defaults[key];
        }
    }),
    View: Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function() {
            this.setElement($('#main'));
        },
        bindings: {
            'input[name=words]': 'words',
            'input[name=type]': 'type',
            'input#okButton': {
              attributes: [{
                name: 'disabled',
                observe:['type','words'],
                onGet: 'okButtonDisabled'
              }],
            }
        },
        okButtonDisabled: function(words) {
            return (!this.model.isDefault("words") ||
                    !this.model.isDefault("type")) ? null : true;
        },
        addDisabledClass: function(words) {
            console.log("is this neccessary?");
            return (!this.model.isDefault("words") ||
                    !this.model.isDefault("type")) ? "" : "disabled";
        },
        render: function() {
            this.stickit();
        }
    })
};

var view = new app.View({model:new app.Model()});
view.render();
```

[Modified JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mp6G9/202/)

If you have many fields, you could change the `isDefault` method to accept an array of keys. Then, loop through the keys and return false if ANY key does not match its' default. Something like:

```
Model: Backbone.Model.extend({
    isDefault: function(keys) {
        for (var i = 0; i<keys.length; i++) {
            if (this.get(keys[i]) !== this.defaults[keys[i]]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
});

View: Backbone.View.extend({
    okButtonDisabled: function(words) {
        return !this.model.isDefault(["words", "type"]) ? null : true;
    }
});
```

#### EDIT:

If you can assume that ALL attributes in the Model are associated with a form input, then you could iterate through each attribute and check for a difference. Something like this:

```
Model: Backbone.Model.extend({
    isDefault: function(keys) {
        for (var key in this.attributes) {
            if (this.get(key) !== this.defaults[key]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
});

View: Backbone.View.extend({
    okButtonDisabled: function(words) {
        return !this.model.isDefault() ? null : true;
    }
});
```

[Updated Abstracted JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mp6G9/203/)

Comment: I am going to accept it soon after I test with my code. At least, I am gonna vote up. I am really thankful. Can't we listen, or bind, or something like that, for whole model object since any field will be related to model value rather then checking against each key? I mean comaparing orginal model with changed model on some event like keyup, change or something when user clicks on form to edit?

Comment: i mean keyup event means there might be some change. So, if we compare orginal model with possible model that might have got change, we can fire enable if the model has changed. This might allow less and good code.

Comment: You could assume that any key up is a change in the field. But, again if the user changes the value back to the default value, you want to disable the "save" button. Backbone does not have a Model method of checking against default values. The "changed" Array is only those Objects that have changed. For example, a change from "apple" to "apples" will be marked as "changed". Likewise, a change from "apples" back to "apple" will still be marked as "changed" because the Model recognizes this as such.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include an option that iterates through ALL model attributes to eliminate the need to pass keys.

Comment: you are fabulous. If I still don't mark your answer as accepted, I am not worth to community. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Corey , how should my input#okButton': {} portion cahnge if <a id="okButton" class="btn" >save</a> is made instead of <input id="okButton" class="btn" >save</input>. making t#okButton'() do not work.

Comment: You probably should open a new question for this...but, you need to change your binding to "a#okButton", change its' attribute.name from "disabled" to "class", then in the okButtonDisabled function, have it return ("" : "disabled") rather than (null : true).

Answer (score 2):

"*set initially the "save" button as disabled.*"
This can be done with HTML markup or in the `initialize` method of your view (or such).

"*If user makes any changes to any of form field, it must enable "save" button.
But, if user enters something in any field so that "save" button is enabled, and again make the field same as original , the "save" button must be disabled again. i.e. editing "apple" to "apppleee" so that "save" is enabled, and reverse "appleee" back to "apple" to disable "save" button again.*"
[How to enable/disable save button of backbone form-view when user changes form content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16108176/how-to-enable-disable-save-button-of-backbone-form-view-when-user-changes-form-c/16108499#16108499) should give you a solution for that part as well.
Basically, you store your model's original state like `myView._model = myView.model.toJSON()`.  When your model change, you compare `this.model.toJSON()` and `this._model` (with the help of `_.isEqual` or just checking some attributes) and enable/disable your button accordingly.

Comment: your answer is helpful.Sorry, I don't have reputation to vote up yet.So, thanks a lot.

Comment: @user2314342 no problem, it can still help you the day you have dynamic attributes and can't use the `defaults` property (that's why I'm not using it in my answer)